# DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("ДЕГРАДАЦИЯ")

x = 50
y = 400
weight = 40
height = 60
speed = 5

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10

lastMove = "right"

bullets = []

class snaryad():
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing) -> object:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)

def drawWindow():
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.x < 500:
            if bullet.x > 0:
                bullet.x += bullet.vel
            else:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys [pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 5:
        x -= speed
        lastMove = "left"
    if keys [pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - weight - 5:
        x += speed
        lastMove = "right"
    if not isJump:
        if keys [pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            if jumpCount < 0:
                y += (jumpCount ** 2) / 2
            else:
                y -= (jumpCount ** 2) / 2
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10
    if keys [pygame.K_f]:
        if lastMove == "right":
            facing = 1
        else:
            facing = -1
        if len(bullets) < 3:
            bullets.append(snaryad(round(x + weight // 2), round(y + height // 2), 5, (255, 0, 0), facing))

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), (x, y, weight, height))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Выходит ошибка:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\ДЕГРАДАЦИЯ.py"
pygame 1.9.6
c:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\����������.py:86: DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), (x, y, weight, height))
[Done] exited with code=0 in 11.009 seconds
```

Comment: здесь кубик должен стрелять, но при нажатии f игра вылетает

Comment: Во-первых, этот не ошибка, а предупреждение. Во-вторых, там написано в чем проблема. В-третьих, минус за бессмысленный заголовок.

Comment: но как теперь эту ошибку исправить?

Comment: почемуто он даже не стреляет

Comment: У вас ответ в вопросе.

Comment: @АлександрЖарков, посмотрите ответ, я подробно написал про ошибку

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка говорящая: `an integer is required (got type float)`. Т.е. ожидается целое число, а получено вещественное.

Смотри в функцию, что в ошибке:

```
pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), (x, y, weight, height))
```

И сразу выделяем: `x`, `y`, `weight`, `height`, т.к. минимум, в одном из них есть вещественное число.

Я облегчу задачу и сразу скажу, что это `y`, из-за такого кода:

```
y += (jumpCount ** 2) / 2
y -= (jumpCount ** 2) / 2
```

Дело в том, что в питоне есть два оператора деления:

- `/` -- деление с результатом как вещественное число, например: `print(5 / 2)  # 2.5`
- `//` -- деление с результатом как целое число, например: `print(5 // 2)  # 2`

Поэтому, **решением будет использование // вместо /**:

```
y += (jumpCount ** 2) // 2
y -= (jumpCount ** 2) // 2
```

---

**PS.**

Подобные ошибки довольно легко находятся и исправляются, например добавив `print` можно понять с каким значениями имеем дело, а после сразу с ними кардинально разобраться, например:

```
x = int(x)
y = int(y)
...
pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), (x, y, weight, height))
```